# Datalist in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

When i select the name, description of particular name should display in below div tag. Please give me the answer

```
 <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers" >
   <option ng-repeat="state in result" value="{{state.name}}">
    </option>
    </datalist>

    <div></div>
```

Json of my project:

```
{
     "states": [
         {
           "name":"Alabama","description":"Hi  iam from   ALabama","description1":"Hi it is from Alabama 2nd description"},
        {"name":"Alaska","description":"Hi  iam from  ALaska","description1":"Hi it is from Alaska  2nd description"}

           ]
 }
```

Angular controller:

```
     var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
        app.controller('statesCtrlr', [ '$scope', '$http',
       function($scope, $http) {
        var url = "json/countries.json";
        $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
            $scope.result = response.states;

            } ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:-

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers" >
   <option ng-repeat="state in result" value="{{state.name}} ng-click"="showDesc(state.name)">
</option>
</datalist>

<div>{description}</div>
```

Controller:-

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
    app.controller('statesCtrlr', [ '$scope', '$http',
   function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.showDesc = function(name){
       // find description for selected state
       $scope.description = // selected state description.
    }
    var url = "json/countries.json";
    $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
        $scope.result = response.states;

        } ]);
```

Comment: Can u please give the answer in detail.. I am new to angular

Comment: Provide on-click="showDesc(state.name)" to all the options in the datalist, so on clicking any option showDesc function is called with the country as argument, using that find the correct description and set the description in the controller scope, which is bound to <>{{description}}</div>. I will try to get a jsfiddle soon.